# Error 0 Could not write to the configuration file,"Joomla can't write any data to configuration.php file"

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have tried to save my FTP layer settings, in a Joomla website, and I received this error

> 0 Could not write to the configuration file

Of course I can do it manually, using an FTP manager, or the hosting's file manager.

But what is the cause of this problem?

And the problem is, Joomla can't write any data to `configuration.php` file.

And what is the solution?

Joomla's Version:3.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same issue as your last question I believe. Permissions issue.

You need to make sure that the *configuration.php* which is a file, is set to **644** in regards to permissions, before you edit it. If this doesn't work, try **temporarily** making it **777** and then reverting it back once you have made your changes.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Lodder,but please tell me setting configuration.php to 644 permission is not going to cause a security issue?

Comment: Well some people set it to 444 just to be on the safe side, so you can do too if you wish